# Login to Admin not working for icecast server

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, admin, icecast, nginx-ingress

I have setup a nearly identical staging server to our production icecast server.

However the one issue I'm running into ( trying to create the mountpoint ) is logging into the admin.

```
==> /var/log/icecast2/access.log <==
10.0.0.42 - - [27/Aug/2018:18:16:05 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 331 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.344 0.106 Safari/537.36" 0

==> /var/log/icecast2/error.log <== [2018-08-27  18:16:05] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Bad or missing password on admin command request (command: )
```

Which doesn't happen on production.

The only difference right now is that I have this staging server setup on an nginx ingress through kubernetes.

Comment: oh dear. unless you are top notch on nginx, please consider not to do that. Way too many problems people keep running into.

Comment: https://wiki.xiph.org/Icecast_Server/known_reverse_proxy_restrictions to give you an idea what you are getting into.

Comment: wow I would have never have thought to check here. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If we compare your log entry with the default Nginx log format:

```
10.0.0.42 - [27/Aug/2018:18:16:05 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401
$remote_addr $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status
```

The `-` between the IP address and the time indicates the `$remote_user` variable was not sent with this request.

This variable takes the value of the user name supplied with the Basic authentication, so if looks like this is not being passed to your Icecast server.

What does your Nginx conf file look like? If you are routing the request to your icecast server with a `proxy_pass` directive you may need to specifically pass the auth header, like this:

```
proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
```

You may also find some of the paths within Icecast don't work properly, but if your Nginx build has the sub_filter module you can rewrite them, something like this:

```
sub_filter_types text/xhtml text/xml text/css;
sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="<external-url>';
sub_filter 'url(/'  'url(<external-url>';
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter_last_modified on;
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
```

There is no reason you shouldn't be able to access your admin pages through Nginx, it just takes a little tweaking. I run a production server in this way.